# Разная ширина столбцов в разных рядках

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, табличная-верстка

Мне нужна таблица состоящая из 3х рядков.

- 1й: 1й столбец шириной в 10%, 2й столбец шириной в 90%
- 2й: 1й столбец шириной в 90%, 2й столбец шириной в 10%
- 3й: 1 столбец шириной в 100%

Имею данный код:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      color: black;
      background-color: pink;
    }
    
    a {
      color: darkgreen;
    }
    
    a:visited {
      color: lightgreen;
    }
    
    a:active {
      color: white;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 20%;
      height: 40%;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="10%">a</td>
      <td width="90%">b</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="90%">c</td>
      <td width="10%">d</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">e</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

В результате: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне решить даную проблему?

Comment: делайте столбцы 10, 80 и 10, и потом объединяйте, как вам надо

Comment: @splash58 не подскажите как именно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите за основу 10 столбцов:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      color: black;
      background-color: pink;
    }
    
    a {
      color: darkgreen;
    }
    
    a:visited {
      color: lightgreen;
    }
    
    a:active {
      color: white;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 20%;
      height: 40%;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="10%">a</td>
      <td colspan="9" width="90%">b</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="9" width="90%">c</td>
      <td width="10%">d</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="10" align="center">e</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```